# iOS Navigation Back Button

Tags: ios, swift

I want to have a back button on the second view controller I have. When it loads now, it does show the back button but I want to change the title from Back to something else. I implemented to viewWillAppear method where I invoke showing the navigation bar. 
The following didn't work:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated);
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = false
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title = "Something Else"

    }
```

Please help me change the title. Should it be in the willAppear or viewDidLoad?

Comment: Have you tried putting it in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: yup didn't work either

Comment: replace the navigationControllers backBarButton with a custom back button...and in the action of back button add code to pop the view Controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this right before the push or popViewController statement in your first view:

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Something Else",style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain ,target: nil,action: nil)
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.backBarButtonItem = backButton
```

Or you can do it in your second view this way:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated);

    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Something Else",style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain ,target: nil,action: nil)
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.backBarButtonItem = backButton
}
```

Comment: popViewController statement? I don't have that I believe...I only have two methods ViewDidAppear and ViewWillAppear

Comment: actually added the second snipper and worked! Thanks mate.

Comment: Happy to help you..:)

Answer (score 1):

Ksa_coder  I have tried the solution for your question and finally I got.You want to add the below coding in second view controller in viewWillAppear method

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) 
{

    super.viewWillAppear(animated);


    var btnBack = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Something Else",style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain ,target: nil,action: nil)


    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.backBarButtonItem = btnBack

}
```

Comment: If my code is helpful,give up vote.Also someone can refer this.

Comment: In my view,I tried to get the solution in this way and I got it.Most preferable way to do this is apply the coding viewWillAppear method once we navigate the second view.

Comment: Some answers can be same.Is there any very different type way implementing show that apart from your answer?

Comment: Even if you agree whether my answer is correct,Can you give up vote?